# Problem in creating File in external storage

Tags: android, file-writing

I made an android app that uses external storage of android mobile!
I Built APK version and tested in some android phones.

In some of the phones my app can't create File in the given directory but in some other phone it can do!

I used the `File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/My App Name");` as the given directory!

It works in some phone but in some other phone it gives the message `no such file or directory`.

Note: In my android version, when i was trying to use the method `getExternalStorageDirectory()` it showed that it can't be used(marking it unusable). But i couldn't find any other method to do it.

How can i solve this problem in this version?

My android studio version is: `android-studio-ide-193.6626763-windows`. (Android Studio 4.0) may be!

Comment: For Android Q add android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" to manifest file to continue under Q.

Comment: Can you explain more please?? :( 
I just want to write some text in that directory. nothing else!

Comment: You can bypass the new limitation in Android 10 only by using the `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage` attribute. But then you'll have the same problem in Android 11, which is coming out very soon.

Answer (score 0):

This is because Android 10 doesn't let you use `getExternalStorageDirectory()` any more. You need to refactor your app to use scoped storage: https://medium.com/@gavingt/refactoring-my-backup-and-restore-feature-to-comply-with-scoped-storage-e2b6c792c3b

Comment: So, can't i access external storage anymore??

Comment: Not with `File` commands, no. You need to use Storage Access Framework: https://en.proft.me/2018/05/24/using-android-storage-access-framework/

Comment: So, they made an easy task hard :( :( 
I need to study more!

Can you provide me some link(s) where i can easily understand how to just write and read a text  file in external storage in new android studio versions?? <3

Thank you.

Comment: The link I posted above shows this already. It's not as hard as it might first appear: https://en.proft.me/2018/05/24/using-android-storage-access-framework/